# Free or unlimited license alternatives to Monoslideshow Flash slideshow?

Tags: website, flash, image-gallery

[monoslideshow](http://www.monoslideshow.com) is a pretty nice flash slideshow player with many options. However it requires a separate license for each site. I am planning to integrate one in a CMS which will host many sites so the Monoslideshow's license scheme won't work for me.

Are there free or unlimited site license alternatives (less than $100) to Monoslideshow?

Comment: Developer recently mentioned that he's working on a developer license. Waiting to see how much it will cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dfGallery](http://www.dezinerfolio.com/dfgallery-2/free-flash-gallery) works similarly to monoslideshow and SlideshowPro, but incredibly, it's FREE.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [AutoViewer](http://simpleviewer.net/autoviewer/). There is a free version that I have used in a couple of projects. The developer also has a few other related projects that may better fit with your needs.

Alternately, [Google's Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) can export selected images to a gallery - something that I've used on a few projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [SimpleViewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/). There's a free version and a Pro version. The Pro version is more customizable and costs $45. As to the license:

> SimpleViewer-Pro may be used to create
>   an unlimited number of websites. Each
>   purchase provides a single-user,
>   single-workstation license.